# DatabaseReference and FirebaseDatabase - cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on an institute level chat messaging application on Android. I'm using Firebase as my Cloud Server. Currently, I'm facing a `Cannot Resolve Symbol error` on `DatabaseReference` and `FirebaseDatabase` at the following line in my `MainActivity`:

```
private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();
```

I want to make chat rooms using Firebase. I know how to do this, as well as how to link Keys and Values of my Firebase Database. I also know how to update the Keys and Values from an Android Device through Firebase Cloud.

But I'm not able to resolve the `Cannot resolve Symbol error`.
Following is the code of my `MainActivity`. I'm still in initial stages of making this app.

```
    package com.ranatalha.realtimechat;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonAddRoom;
    private EditText editTextAddaChatRoom;
    private ListView listViewChatRooms;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> list_of_rooms = new ArrayList<>();

    private String Entered_Username;


    private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonAddRoom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddRoom);
        editTextAddaChatRoom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddaChatRoom);
        listViewChatRooms = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewChatRooms);

//************Creation of an array list to store the list of active chat rooms************
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_of_rooms);

        listViewChatRooms.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
//*****************************************************************************************
        request_user_name();

        buttonAddRoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void request_user_name(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter Your Name:");

        final EditText inputUsername = new EditText(this);
        builder.setView(inputUsername);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Entered_Username = inputUsername.getText().toString();

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
                request_user_name();
            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your app-level build.gradle

Comment: For [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) with special attention to [adding the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: @Arel suggested an answer and it worked like a charm. I added 2 more dependencies in my build.gradle (Module:app) file which are `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0' and
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'` ... Thanks a lot for your reply and concern to my question @qbix and @AbAppletic :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Can you please double check if you have these dependencies into your `build.gradle` (Module:app) file?

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'    
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
```

The error goes away after adding those.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot @Arel for helping me with this. Really grateful to you for this :)

Comment: No problem. Happy Coding!

Comment: That did fix it. I didn't see that in the firebase.google.com walkthru setup guide.  I guess it is missing from that?

Comment: Hi @daylight If you haven't seen the docs yet, you may read it here https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

Comment: Firebase should hire you for that answer. Lifesaver!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these dependencies into your

1) build.gradle (Module:app) file.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
```

2) build.gradle (Top-level build)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

3) add google-services.json in app module in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
```